# how to add watermarks in reacts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could you please tell me how to add watermarks in react js.
I am taking help from this site
http://brianium.github.io/watermarkjs/text.html

Here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/8lr7krkk3l

```
handle = () => {
    console.log(watermark);
    watermark([
      "https://www.hometown.in/media/product/88/5392/57299/1-product_500.jpg"
    ])
      .image(
        "dsda".lowerRight("watermark.js", "48px Josefin Slab", "#fff", 0.5)
      )
      .then(function(img) {
        console.log(img);
      });
  };
```

**I want to show a image having watermark (any text) in that**

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one of the following packages for watermark an image.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamic-watermark

https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-watermark

Answer (score 0):

several issues with your code

1. change `"dsda"` to watermark.text
2. you need to change cross origin request settings, see http://brianium.github.io/watermarkjs/docs.html#watermark
3. to answer the main question, how to do this with react, you would need to extract the src attribute from the output and pass it to your render fn, where you would create the  with the watermarked src.

Comment: could you please share codesandbox link.i will try and update you

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = {
  init: function (img) {
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  }
};

// Consider using options if using URL
watermark(["https://www.hometown.in/media/product/88/5392/57299/1-product_500.jpg"
    ], options)
      .image(
        watermark.text.lowerRight("Add text here", "48px Josefin Slab", "#fff", 0.5)
      )
      .then(function(img) {
        console.log(img);
      });
```